# onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) only gets called once during the lifecycle of an Activity

Tags: android

I noticed that

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
```

only gets called once.  I need this to get called every time the menu is displayed because I add/remove items from the menu depending on the application state.

is this possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes. To do that you need to use:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
```

That code will be executed every time before your options menu is shown.
More information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29).

Answer (score 9):

If you want the menu to change every time it is opened there is something else to be taken into account depends on the Android sdk version.

This is what the developer guide says:

> If you want to modify the options menu based on events that occur during the activity lifecycle, you can do so in the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method. This method passes you the Menu object as it currently exists so you can modify it, such as add, remove, or disable items. (Fragments also provide an onPrepareOptionsMenu() callback.)
>
> On Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls onPrepareOptionsMenu() each time the user opens the options menu (presses the Menu button).
>
> On Android 3.0 and higher, the options menu is considered to always be open when menu items are presented in the action bar. When an event occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call invalidateOptionsMenu() to request that the system call onPrepareOptionsMenu().

Comment: +1 for including the part about invalidateOptionsMenu()...just call getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu() somewhere after you set your boolean or whatever you're using to switch between menus.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to dynamically update menu items?
override onPrepareOptionsMenu()